# transfer request from urlrequest.Request to aiohttp ClientSession

Tags: python-3.x, request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I do have a really simple, and i would say a silly question.

i'm have a simple peace of code:

```
  payload_json = json.dumps({                                                       
      "channel": "#general",                                                        
      "username": "webhookbot",                                                     
      "text": msg,                                                                  
      "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"                                                       
  })
  data = urlencode({"payload": payload_json})                                
  opener = urlrequest.build_opener(urlrequest.HTTPHandler())        
  req = urlrequest.Request(config.SLACK_URL)                        
  response = opener.open(req, data.encode('utf-8')).read()
```

as you can see nothing complicated, but, when i do this with aiohttp:

```
payload_json = json.dumps({                                                       
      "channel": "#general",                                                        
      "username": "webhookbot",                                                     
      "text": msg,                                                                  
      "icon_emoji": ":ghost:"                                                       
})
data = urlencode({"payload": payload_json})
response = await session.post(                                    
  config.SLACK_URL,                                             
  data=bytes(data, 'ascii'),                                    
  headers={'Content-Encoding': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
)
```

i'm always getting error: slack response  invalid_payload, which mean that i sent wrong body to the slack server.
i'm kind of lost, what i did wrong?

Comment: Sicnce you're trying to send json request, did you try `json` keyword instead of `data` in `session.post` ? Accodring to [docs](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/client.html#json-request) this is the way to go

Comment: No, it is not a json request. I need to send urlencoded data